# How to share the git commit log with the customer without giving access to the repository?

Tags: git

I want to share the progress of the project with the customer. I need to show him that im working on it constantly. The best way to do is to show the comit log. But to show it, I have to give him access to my repo (Bitbucket or Github). How can I do this without giving access to the repo?

Comment: Is it a private repo?

Comment: @AliGajani Yes it is private

Answer (score 3):

I have seen another alternative:

- set a post-receive hook (or a webhook) on the private repo (server side) which will:

  - do a git log and redirect the result in a text file
  - save that text file in a dedicated repo (which includes only the log text file)

That way, you give access to that log repo, and the client can follow the log in it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, clone your private repository onto your computer and do `git log`.

Then copy around this information to your client/customer.

*Short Tip*

I would copy it using `git log | pbcopy` on my Mac OSX.

This copies the `git log` contents into your clipboard.